# Django on GCP failed to import CSV file using import-export

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, django-import-export

I have setup a model in Django and there is a requirement to allow editor to update records using CSV import.

I installed import-export, following the guide from [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/) and setup the importer. The importer works as expected during development. However, the importer shows an error when the code is running on Google Cloud.

While local dev is running everything locally, staging and prod instances are all running from GCP:
The Django instance is running on Cloud Run, using storage from Google Storage (both media and web). I know the Django instance cannot use the default tmp storage from import-export when it is running from Google Cloud. I have changed to use [MediaStorage](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_tmp_storages.html). However, after I select the CSV file from admin, click "Submit", I'm getting the following error:

```
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
('`data` must be bytes, received', <class 'str'>)
Exception Location: /venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py, line 290, in _prepare_request
Raised during:  import_export.admin.import_action
```

When I go through the Traceback the error I noticed that the upload failed seems to be because during the upload process, for some reason, the google library switched to upload the CSV as resumable media.

```
......../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py, line 290, in _prepare_request
        .. _sans-I/O: https://sans-io.readthedocs.io/
        """
        if self.finished:
            raise ValueError("An upload can only be used once.")
        if not isinstance(data, bytes):
            raise TypeError("`data` must be bytes, received", type(data)) …
        checksum_object = _helpers._get_checksum_object(self._checksum_type)
        if checksum_object is not None:
            checksum_object.update(data)
            actual_checksum = _helpers.prepare_checksum_digest(checksum_object.digest())
            metadata_key = _helpers._get_metadata_key(self._checksum_type)
```

The "data" for upload is the content of the CSV file therefore it's a text string. It looks like this is how the failed.

The site is using django-storages to enable both web and media using Google Storage. I tested the file upload from the admin forms and they are all working as expected (including text, csv and images).

In order to make the importer working for the editor to use, I have to set IMPORT_EXPORT_SKIP_ADMIN_CONFIRM = True, so that the CSV file upload will not use tmp storage.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use the [DB Cache](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#import-confirmation) as your storage backend.  If this is not possible, then I suggest overriding [MediaStorage](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_tmp_storages.html#import_export.tmp_storages.MediaStorage) with a subclass which can write the file contents in the correct form.  You can then set this subclass as the [storage class](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#import-export-tmp-storage-class).

I haven't tried this but it would be useful to update this post if you get it working.

**UPDATE**

I think this is a [bug in the import process when using `MediaStorage`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1589).  There is logic in the import process to decode the import bytes if `MediaStorage` is used.

The workaround (for now) would be to create a subclass, as this won't force the decode().  This should work:

```
class MyMediaStorage(MediaStorage):
   pass
```

(then reference the above class in `settings.py`).